# Writing methods in async/await way

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

This is a Books Donation project and I am trying to write some methods in **async/await** way.

***BooksRepo :class that has all the methods***

```
class BooksRepo {
    constructor() {
        this.fse = require('fs-extra');
        this.catalogFilePath = '../data/catalog.books.json';
    }


    async readFileAsync(filePath) {
        let data = await this.fse.readFile(filePath);
        let parsedData = await JSON.parse(data);

        return parsedData;
    }



    async getBook(bookName) {
        let books = await this.readFileAsync(this.catalogFilePath);
        let book = books.find(b => b.title == bookName);
        return book;
    }

}
```

***catalogFile: Example of how it structured***

```
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "Unlocking Android",
    "isbn": "1933988673",
    "pageCount": 416,
    "publishedDate": {
      "$date": "2009-04-01T00:00:00.000-0700"
    },
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/AKIAJC5RLADLUMVRPFDQ.book-thumb-images/ableson.jpg",
    "shortDescription": "Unlocking Android: A Developer's Guide provides concise...",
    "longDescription": "Android is an open source mobile phone platform based on the Linux operating ...",
    "status": "PUBLISH",
    "authors": [
      "W. Frank Ableson",
      "Charlie Collins",
      "Robi Sen"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "Open Source",
      "Mobile"
    ]
  },
```

***app : class this is how I am trying to call the methods***

```
let booksRepo = new BooksRepo();
    booksRepo.readFileAsync(booksRepo.catalogFilePath).then(result=> console.log(result));

    let books = booksRepo.getBook("Android in Action, Second Edition");

    console.log(books)
```

**I get this error** *BooksRepo is not defined*

I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Please tag this question with the language you're using.

Comment: Seems like you are not exporting or importing (or both) the `BooksRepo` class. Thou it's hard to tell as we can't see the entire files

Comment: @DSCH I did export it and now it gives me this error                                     Promise { <pending> }
(node:71617) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../data/catalog.books.json'

Comment: That means that `'../data/catalog.books.json'` is not the correct path to the file.

Comment: @LyleUnderwood okay thanks I corrected the path and it worked :)

Comment: `JSON.parse` is not asynchronous, you should not `await` it.

Comment: Btw, it's probably not a good idea to read the file again on every `getBook` call. Instead, make the data a property of the `BookRepo` instance and [read the file on initialisation, before constructing the object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24686979/1048572).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks you have a problem with exports/imports.

First, you have to export the class in the file it is in:

```
module.exports = BooksRepo;
```

Then to import it in the file where it's used:

```
var BooksRepo = require('./books-repo');
```

Alternatively:

```
export default class BooksRepo { ...
```

And

```
import BooksRepo from './books-repo.js';
```